# jKit paginate automating the page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automation

I have this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bwk43/4/

I have been looking for a while for a method of turning a table into a pages like so but I am still struggling to find something that can automate the page change every 10 minutes or so.

I am using this in a TV display for some information from a database and it needs to change automatically as the display its on is somewhat like a board for flight times in a airport so no keyboard and mouse will be attached.

The only events I can see for this plugin are triggered when pages load so not sure how to tie these in with the initial load.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Plugin Source:
http://jquery-jkit.com/commands/paginate.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it adds an li list at the bottom so you can just call click on them

```
(function(){
    var waitTime = 1000*60*10;
    function showPage() {
        var lis = $(".jkit-pagination").find("li");  //get the lis
        var next = lis.filter(".active").next();     //find the next li after the active one
        if (!next.length) next = lis.eq(0);          //if it is the last li, switch to first
        next.click();                                //click it
        window.setTimeout(showPage,waitTime);      //set timer to do it all over again
    }    
    window.setTimeout(showPage,waitTime);          //wait for initial page to have its time
})();
```

Comment: Many many thanks for that speedy response I was thinking along those lines but I need to work on my skills with JS/Jquery :(

Comment: Quite funny I removed this code from my app around a year ago and only just realized it was missing and had to re-add it and tried to up vote this answer without realizing this was my own question.